# Saving image in database field to file on server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to save data from a table directly to the servers file system using this t-sql:

```
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
DECLARE @Name varchar(100)
DECLARE @FileName varchar(100)
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Id, [FileName] FROM FilesTable
OPEN MyCursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor 
INTO @ID, @Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT @FileName = 'd:\Temp\' + convert(varchar(200), @Name)

SET @command = 'bcp "SELECT FileBytes FROM FilesTable WHERE ID = ' + convert(varchar(18),     @Id) + '" queryout "' + @FileName + '" -T -n'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command, no_output

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor 
INTO @Id, @Name

END

CLOSE MyCursor 
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

The table is filled with solid data. accessing this data with a C# program works.
I did configure advanced options gave permission to use xp_cmdshell
When I run this query i don't get any error but no file was written.
I also don't see anything in the logs, (maybe I am looking in the wrong location?)

What am I doing wrong? Or what can I do to checdk 'under the hood'?

Comment: You might find help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325338/fastest-way-to-export-blobs-from-table-into-individual-files

  [1]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from Patrick and the answer in [fastest way to export blobs from table into individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325338/fastest-way-to-export-blobs-from-table-into-individual-files) I was able to store the images on my fileserver.

we ended up writing a CLR function something like the one given.