# How to make a blob field appear on Crystal Report XI?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Within our database we have invoices being saved and uploaded as a PDF; however within Crystal Report the field is marked as a blob. When attempting to drag this field onto the report it comes out blank, is there a way to have the image appear on CR XI, from a blob field?

```
I am using Crystal Report 11.5.11.1470
I am using a SQL Database, Syntax is SQLServer
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, and experience, you cannot display a blobulized PDF in a Crystal report.

https://scn.sap.com/thread/3207588

> Please note that Crystal Reports does not support anything other than 'Images' in Blob fields. If that Blob field has text, pdf file, doc file or just anything other than an image, Crystal Reports will return Blank.

There is a false statement floating around that you can add an OLE PDF object to Crystal and then change the location of the PDF to reflect the Blobulized field, but **this does not work - a blob field cannot be used in a formula**.

One option would be to use another program/utility to retrieve the PDF from the blob, run the Crystal Report and export to PDF, then combine both of the files. Depending on the report and the blob, that may not work.

Otherwise, you could possibly convert the blob to another data type and then use Crystal to display the data.

Comment: Are you aware of any programs where I can do this?

Comment: Depending on your environment and business requirements, you'll probably have to write some code to accomplish this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325338/fastest-way-to-export-blobs-from-table-into-individual-files - You can do it with TSQL (MSSQL) using a Common Language Runtime (CLR) method, or you could write a Java, C#, .Net, etc,. application to do this. How frequently will you have to do this? Who will the users be?

Comment: Frequency would be on a daily basis where images are being uploaded onto our database and report being generated daily too.