# Extracting .bmp and .pdf files from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pdf, sql-server-2008-r2

I just inherited a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, everything has been restored and all tables can be queried without a problem. However, in this database `.bmp` and `.pdf` files have been stored in an attachments table, for the life of me I cannot find any code or instruction on how to view the actual files that in the table. The table contains from what I can tell from other sources, the basic field names for storing documents within the server, below is the basic code to pull the table data.

```
SELECT 
    [FileSeq],
    [TableName],
    [ID1], [ID2], [ID3],
    [FileName],
    [Description],
    [FileObject]
FROM 
    [SXWAG].[dbo].[Attachment]
```

**Question**: where can I find examples of code or instructions that I can use to extract the actual `.bmp` or `.pdf` files from this table?

This would be a sample file we are trying to extract.

```
FileSeq TableName   ID1 ID2 ID3 FileName    Description FileObject
3117752 WorkOrder   C5166148    NULL    NULL    WOC5166148_Compl_Signature.bmp  Signature coming from PDA.  Signer name is: Doug Griffo 0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200000265000001390806000000D12B57360000000473424954080808087C0864880000200049444154789CEDDD4FAC5C679AD7F15F8F7ADF15897D9D1E366C50B9C31A9DA259C04860A78105D2A8AF352DB6B619D8C6B911621927DDC0EC62BB8725729CEE9E6D92EB66038BD8719648D8372D21162370798310124CB178EFE95BBEBE7FEA79DEBFE79CEF477AD5994C6E9DF7549D3AF59CF77DDEE7FD9E0000400A3724AD255D3BF9BF8F25FDFAA401000020A3A5A44F24BD92B4BDA0BD94B4A8D541000080295B4A7AA08B03B1F3DA41959E0200004CD042D207BA7C64ECB2D697EF320000C0B4F40A53919E606C682F8AF71A000060221692EE292E18DB6DB7CB761F000060FC528C8E315A06000010E103A50DC6765B57EE34000000C66921E92BE50BC8B6926E153B1B00008011EAE55F5969695F943A21000080B1B9ADFCC11879650000001758487AAC7201D9D0A8F20F0000706225E9A9CA07645B857D3201000066EFBACAE48F5DD448F6C71BFEA076070000A8E09EA45F4B7A27C16BBD9674F3E4352D7E90E0D8000000A394BADCC53385CDC925E97DE3DF3ECA79A2000000AD4A9D3F7678E6F5D7C6BFA72C060000989D94F9631B857A6667AD8DAF43590C0000302B29B74B3AD2C5A52C168ED70300009885FBCA375D791EEB6B76D167080000D0B085D2E58F6D14A63FF7613DE63AE6240100005A963220DB5D5DB98F2F8CAFBFF69E24A6873A650080295948FA52D2BB095EEBA1A41F4BFA9DE16F9E27382E0000C0A8AD946E85E51D671F0E8CC761FF4BFCDEF76A7700008004560A2B23632BF4BF96F49EA4DF46BCC64B493FDCE3BFBB2FE99F451CA7B6DEF8DFC7BCA7B34050060018BB5401D937927E22DB74E5797A494FF638D68F1582C016F40AEFE33B0A3974BB41E5F0EF533BD69BEFF5739DBE1FBBFFFCADDA799FB2222803008CD94261642A36687828E95F28DD8F7F2FE9973ABFE4C51385E0AF56A0310460D724FDE8E47FC760A310A049A741DBF0BFDF293E980600004EA95659EE537FCCEBA6A40F1502B10F659FF24B6121E9B6C2E85C8A7CBB96DB91A4C70A9F698DF71A0080D949119059EA8F8DD10D8500A576A054BB3D565880C1A20A000032B0D6033B2F205B15EF757E4B499F28DD2AD4A9B507B2D59D0300009788DD3AE999A617901D681ED39329DA2B85FD5001004084BB8A0FC8A6348DD52BDDEE05736B4F35AD6B01008062AE8B806CB094F495EA0736636F4FC57426000026B1D5FA3F2BDFE52C960A7951B5839929B5579A4EB00E004056B12B2DA73042B650C88322813F4F7BBAFF470100C07CC524F64F2120EB453056A2DDDFF703C9858AFE008096DD96F40BE7DFBE56D82E68CC5BF4DC56283A9B639BA318DFC95E41BFCFD08FD46E48FA4DAD83139401005AD5EBEA3D242FF25AD25AA7DBF28CCD422177EC27858EF79D4290F5446F6E6724BDBD47652ABB7B6A2E74BADDD342D2DF93F437321CF32A2F25FDF50AC70500A069DE29BBB11786CD3D5DB991F473852DA0D6654EC9E44075A731BBEC670800C088C4D4233BA8D0DF54EE295FB0F1B9A4F7CA9D8A4BEC2ADB146D9DFB240100188B5EFE1FD47B15FA9BC24A798AC01E4BBAA371D4E2EA543F20DBEA741A150080595B487A21DF8FE9B30AFD8DB55048E64F1D8C1C691C89F5BB5AD8996093FD2C2FF1FD9A07070A58E97439FC6E52E9526155D6AEB3C9AD4F76FEF9B7393A07E02D7725FDA1E3EF5E4BFA71E2BEE4B65298523C7B2F8AF19DC26ACD3F4FF89A25DC95F46EC4DFBF569AD2271F27780D60F686A7CD23E51BFE3E9274A8F0F439F6BA47408B62B6511ADBA8D081D2DEAB360AF7A731DE9B7AC59DFB81A42F225F63AB718EB402CDA99518FA8DA44F34BE1F03A0450BF9BFC7B72BF437C6074A7B2F7AA871E48C5DC43B5D3D046492F428E235B60A2396630C6881A6B4B05267AB50DBE6B6F852035EDE1FD531ED69B990F458E9EE3BCF34FE87C254AB6CDF37FEED570A65413ED4B8035AA0292986AC53B707E24B0E58DC96EFBBB6D1781E8452AFAE7CA0F19CFB453AF91FAACFAEB2B506659F663B2B60A63AD50FC0AEBA69F6B94E1E988895FCDFB1EB15FAEB715DE946F4371A771DB65D294747D7C6D7F822CF2901F3B556FDC06BDFE06CEC4FB4402EDED1EEB1D4234B993FF64CD31985EFE57B0F5EEAFCFBE9DAF83A046540626BD50FB8F66DAF34BE64642037EF763A17FD30B72475FED8D44A357883F18BB6CF5A1B5F87A00C48EC9AEA075BD6F658EDFF980025C4ACB6EC2BF4D72265FED846E399A6DD572FDF7B71D5832D411950D94BD50FB4ACEDA5C6BD59329082778FC7D6A72D53E68F4D69BA729767946C9F1A620465406531C5266BB6572230C37C7993FB5B2FEE99327F6CAAB9A8BD7CEF47BFC76B1394010DF0E6A5D46EAF1456900273933A9FA8B6D4F96377CA76BF28CF67BF6FF98AD10765EC7D8929F8F7927E27E99F4B7AEFCCFFEFB54EF7B3DC5CF0CF672D75BA17DD4A218134C713EB3B0A4BBBFFEE493F81393850B8E6AD3ED6C5DFD99A560AA35A31FB360E5E2BDCC3A6BAD7EE35F93EFB7F9DBA2300C66DA550F9F989D28F98DD2F7616405DDEE4FE568BC4923F66F3A9F28D922D8CAFDBE4481900BB85C2F4C273A50BCCA6520C12B88C774B9D16BF1F29F359A79A3FB6AB93EFBDE9F67CFDB5F17509CA80095A2A6C061C7B5326BF0C53E71D25FBB24667F7906A846CCAF963BB3E92FDBDB16C85B436BEF6A3C8F301D0B014C1194F6E9832EF28598BC9FD2916176DD47EBDB5943C416C6778FDB5F1B5DF8F3B1D0063D04B3A96FF464DD57F4C917794ACD59A649EDCA8DD3687FCB15D9E20D63A9265DD909CA00C988985C24DD773B37EA5E9E796607E3CA364AD26F74BFE921E5BCD237FEC2CCFFBD51B8F610DCAD611E70360646202B3564707000FEF28598BC9FD036B0030B4B9E48FEDEA647F9F3C7984D6C06FED3B1DC0AF57B8B1F59AD750792B160A4FFB9E9B7757BEBB40169E51B297557ABABF5EB6F3995BFED82ECFE7EF09C8AD4159E73C1FC0EC40E73F993E16C15969D69BF7D048FAC7144C71946CF0A5F63B97B9E58F9DF542F600D6C37A8D01D9EDB3D5077B2E96E7DD7879AE4FD6988E298E920DF64951F85CF3CB1FDBE57928FDC8711C6BE158823264B792F454FB5D8C4F2BF571AE160A3F34D69B06A36518B3298F920D160ADB3F9D3D876349372BF6AB159E55AAD71CC7591B8FC1BD15595D345D7959BB51A5A7F3E5ADFEDD55E82B90C29447C9CE5A2804066BCD7BAA72972728F70E1858175E588AD2027B5B4AFA4ABE1F7BCF1031E2EC9B83C2CD035360CD251ADB28192EE7A94DE6FDFCAD2372B79CC701CEB590F4817CC1D8D018BE2DAF17A3659807CF0FF2B32A3D452E9EDA64DEFC3BCA61A01ACF54252330EDF0E458F059616C4A140B45BB3A95BDCF950AFE80DF5BC93F55795E639AA08E4EBECFAB2BDF55C0A593FDFA6E75D371F8DC92FD1AF0E6395F331E67AC798B68C442FE920A5C946DF2E496910388B1F08C06F390382D8F54EE37C93A554EEA0EDC7AF94A295CD636A24E596DBDEC9FDB8B2A3D056C3C2BEEBCC542D1AE920F9D1F198FC546E430DBA7082C01D9B87946CB286382D679A6ADEE56E92972B921FB35D0451CEF6BE3B118958549AF3489FC67DBDCB7FA684D2FFB6748C23F5AE72983D1198FB152F8FEF42261BB45D691ABD8741AEBF5E6294E8B998A2D7371517B206E5E2DB28E96BDAAD34D602F9E11924786D7BFAEF3D3391E8807CE965803F398A9CBB5F158DB8863614616DA7F8B244BDB88A1DA96796A39318589565993BBB7DABF0CC6FD2B5E873D7DDBD0A9EC3DCD5AC99F247F5CC9B267A5A57D2E9E1E5BB750089C2D9FAB65640128C5B321F4BED35657056443634FDFFA3C0F9A31B338D67A7824F9E3522BA5CF1F3B164518C7C4533E00684DAE2D75F60DC82CAF897CACA3A5B12357ECF98C643C37B1CBDA46D2CDA26780143C793824AAA235D61FE38DAE1E21B106645BB118A6366B9014B307A5B568EC56E456E302A903B28FC5C53666D6294C4603D012CFD4E555C1932720DB8A9CA19AD62AFB80692DBFC2F436CE9532207B26A62AA7C03A85495E045AE2B9A75DF663EC0DC808CAEAB226DDC7160DB68ECEB22B0ADED22B4D30B6917458B8EFC8C7FAC4C70F0F5A622DDE7951827F8A55E831D36188634DBA8F9D6A269F0C515225F51F89559553B3164119C6A993FD1E76DE88458A806C9F3C35E463FDBC62D2303CF9645DC4F130319DD20464770AF71BE558AE038AC8A2159E6D95CE4E5DA6AAD348AE653D6BD93FAF9800DA7ADDC5EE1A80094971C379260A234E9DF59A005A103B754940360DA583A4D253A59810EBC573B61D8921F939386FFB188232B4AC93FD7EB63B754940361DD6A4FB9820C9B3DA976B0492E256116D15F674C33C588377A0B698A94B02B269B1A6E7C47C6E9EDA8E5DC4F13011B7454086FD5983B2AE4A2F8153DEA94B02B269F124DDC7D427B39610229F0CD1B5C808C8E6C71A94ADABF412083C5348B7946615FA46D2F5FCA7883D597FEF62EB93BD301E8FFA6433177BD321209B2782328C89E7C1F38F94262063D1535BAC23578F228EE51995A33ED98C758ABBE97C56BCC768054119C6C49AD8FDDF44403655D691AB9802BF9E3C46CC546C9EC433B1CA72CEAC41199B92A3266B80F5BF8DFF3D01D93874B27F96EB88E359EF9331A37218B998806C2312B7E7CEFA2307D4B2565C804540361D9E696C2F6F1E236628A6F405371C48E56E6C40AC8F444086C07A2DC46C11E70900BB88E361A4626B91B1AC1B124119C6C39A434440365DD6B228EF471C8B5218B8526C4076BB7C97D120CFB03C5043270232049EFBD63AE278D6140F4A61CCC842D263C5DD74287D81C15AB66B27660A0088E159FD666D2C7A1A074F657DAFD994C2F87EED0E8CD042D29792DE8D788DC7927E96A63B00504C9FF9F5BF91F46349AF331F07F1FEB6F1BF7F1671AC7FE0F89B5F471C0F2391627B109E02719675F42166335F20466CAD31EE8DD361CD278B994EB41E8B521833902220DB889B0EDE665DC114932C0B78AD952F20FB5CDC1BC7C4934FE69D4EA41406DEB2549A808CC4559CC75A109115BBA8E17DE509C8C8AF1D9FB5EC9FB337E8A61406DEC006BAC8CD7A7DADABF41273677D7820209B2E6B80FE34E25894C2C0EF5D17FBB5212FCA61602C5207648765BB8F84AC017A4C3E19A53020C937644A4006ABB5780A44FBD64A1B9031053F6ED6CFDB9B4F369B5218B8DC0722204319D69597D428430DFF56046408D6B27FE69DF3589E3C464C4C6C957E02325858F325587989D21692FE97D2DC1709C8C6CF1A28C58CEE530A63C65294BC20208395751F417ED450D24AE19EC67D11036B3E99B7AE22A530666C25023294E7B9E95CABD253CCD181D2148BE5BE382DD6CFDFFB2049298C994A51F2821B0F3CAC7BC76DEA741333745BF1F7C4ADA463715F9C92B5CA054A8F8CC78929BB8146A45861B955D81E6459B8EF183F6B6E0649FE2821455EED705FA44AFFB494CA27F3CC22500A63E4EE891B0FEAB2E66690E48F9C1692BE529AFBE203715F9C226BE2BD379FCC3360B2761E0B0D48F52448356AC4B04E9B537F07B9A4CAABDD4AFAB3C27D47199ED12B6F3E9975EA92D48E11BB2B0232D4E7298AC8C8037248B173C9D0FEB270DF518E3507762B5F3E9927F8F38EC8A132CF879D32FA0706D6A2B154F2470E290A65F3E3380F1FC9762D7813EF3D5397CC228C546C623F1B8B2315EBF03C4511915AEA806C2BEA444D99359FCC9B783FD5A9CB9F4A7A2CE9FF29F4FB1B85EFE0AC67403C5B36EC7EF02CED462AD6E922466791CA42E9F26ACF36EAE84D53A732A357539CBAFCA9A4FFAA8BFBFF4A338E2DBC4119252F9092279FACABD1514CCE52E912FAC73A62013B6BBAC556BE11A0294D5D5E158C9D0DCC663962E649543CD24CDF2C645372EF3860F081D225F49FD7A8A3375DD62945EFB53085A94BEF4AE6D647FCB279A9FDDF2456582287527BC7015278A87CAC7CC1D8D0A8A3375D25AE85294C5DAE24FD0FF9BF43B3D46BBF37871C1EE462FDA2722DC22B65FDB1ABDABACC29A130CF0C9327B770EC53970B8592307C871C0E14863DCF7B535861899CD6B27F51BB0AFDC4F8A5AC3FC6753A5F9FCA761D78D32DC63E759962DBC675E94EB76421E98EA4273BED8EC81F435EE493A1841CE52EC6F40389745EC8762D78A614A73075690D2ACF6B000A2BB5771CE629E5FE95964692FF3479568A7BA614C73E7529D97385B9D7039595DC3B0EF3B3926D21D365EDFF18FF7B6FA150B4CD5AC57FEB3CCED8A72EA5B8A06C23A6FF81E24AED1D87F93950BAFCB16792FEB3F16F78789826EBD4A567E791294C5D4AFE9C320AD30395581366BD7BC7615E5256E7FF5CBE1FC975EE9344719DECD781679BAD294C5D4AE17BB36FB1D8A13D1479EC4035D6A74EA6847099A5D296BB383C795D4F1E11A6C753C5BF731C670A53978395A4FFA9FD82B165A53E0250B9BDE3300FBDD24D579E2D03B436FE3D23BAD3645D94E4B90EA63275B96B25E9FFCA198C7D3F77EF004892FEA1E36F7E9DBC179882DB927E91E8B5BE91F41349BFDBF9777FD3F81A2D8F5CC0A793F4B78C7FF34BC7713C3541FFC2F137257D2BE9AF298C38AF24BD23E9B942D9ADD7F5BA056057A9BDE3305DA9B74B7AA0F3F359ACB5F4D85E697A98BA043069D6A9264FC22CA62BF57649772E399675693FD7EAF430750960B2D6B2DF7C3C7BC7619A5296BBD828E4A35DC61A94AD539C249AD1C97E5DCD79D5258091B1166064881E837B4A373AF64CFB2DBFB7BE6E177B92680A539700268DAD9560B550DAE9CA0786E35A5F1BD3622DDDC3D42580D1606B2558F54A3B5D69B99ED6C6D77FE93D4934C953A3CE534FD1331AC7D42580689EBC89AE4647D184DB4A138C6D251DCBBE7DCBDA780C56094F8B67AF4B4FFEAB75F680A94B0049B0B512F691BADCC5917CDBB7584730D875625A4A4C5D76C6636C35A3A9CB3FA8DD0160E2FE91F1BF3FCAD20BB46C25E94B8522AE297C28E9EFC857A8F207C6FF9E6298D37143D21F1AFFE6978EE3FCD4F137FFCEF13700F0064F7EC6BA4647514DEA72179E0AE9BB281C3B5FD651FDAD7CA916D6D138F216012461FD81236F625EEE2BDD74E533A5D9E0D85AA680E4EBE9B03E1C7CE93846A9850400F0166B32EBA33ADD44614BA52F77E1C91F3B0F8563E7C9B320C9B34ABCD44202007803A530709E5EE9A62B735C330465F364FDDCB7F23D0894584800006FA11406CEFA40E982B163D9CB5DECC31A30A61AA1433D9DECD79F6754FF86E338ECAB0A20096B6E0E4F84D3B590F495D2056447CA170C59FB82F1F324F87B72094B2D240080B758471C48669DA695D24E571E66EE2F41D9BC2CE4BB3E3D4A2C240080B77886E9D7353A8AAC5256E74F51EE621F0465F3E249B3F01472F5DC13C9B1059084758511A530A6257575FE54E52EF64150362FD615E25B85C52A56D6748EADC857049088758511A530A663A550EC32554096B2DCC53E08CAE6C35333CC53C8D5B3129D7B2280243C373A86E9A721F574658DEBC2D24716A78C9B27F1DEB31AB2540D340078CB5DD96F400CD3B761A5F0637043B6E9C2D4D395C7CA53EE621F967E7E51A98F88E74DF0F7DCABAC35D048E700908C75EA921FB67A560AAB198F74FE67F34AD227BA3C404A3D5DF9B9EA05E9EB3DFAC7B53B0DB764BF363D09FE5DA1E300C05B3C539714472CAF97BD6ED863BD3D7A96B218EC56F9CB5D5C652D82B2B9B03E3C6EE5DBEEC813FCB19F2A80243CFBBA75353A3A53371457C4F595C2F4E632F275CEB68D7C2BDA52EB44503607BDECD7A8377FD0BABA93A94B00C958733448942E237510F557095FEB486DE5145AFB8FF1F124F87B12EF3BC77128A20D2009CF0A23A62EF33B50DA8AFA29DBC719CFDB8BA06CDA3CE52936F23D3878660E3C53A400F016EB0AA3ADDA1A2199A27BAA1F785DF42357A23ABF0741D9B4954AF097EC796B9E1A6800F0164F823FC511F3BAAFFAC1D779AD64757E0F82B2692B95E0EFB927DE759E1300BCA1548E06F6E3A91557A2B5385D791641D974F5B27FBEDE4DC159F404A08A4EF69B8F37470357F3FCF0E46E2D4F579E65ADB9D655E9253C3C2916DE8747163D01A8C2332A133B4CDF2B6CE973A8364A29B4C4333D93B3B53E5D7996F5877B5DA597B0EAE57B98F0B8E138168B9E0044F36E55D2195EBF57785AFD4497579EBF9DE07CC6CEB30236671BC374E5590465D3E41925F396A7F0A47374CE6301C0EF7946C9CEAE645A29045E873ADDF2E7A2E0EBAA762FCB598E87B55065AED64A31588F47B29D2BB991EDEBE5BB8E3BE7F1AC0FAA2C7A0210CD3B4AF64021E8FAC6F1B7FBB4B1060329D40EC6B6AABB77650AEFCB76BEEFD7E9260C3CA3649F398FE599BA24B00710ADD5157E734D985DABFE7B7F27F749164050362DBD7CD772E73C9E67EA72CC0F31001AE01D252BD5E6A853DDF77C2A7BF6598B8B7A0B8BA20C4F90E4FD4C3DBB05307509205AABA364435B673BF3B6D57CCFA7129CAC653B6F36256F5727DFB5DC398FE75968C3D4E519DFAFDD0160248695907F2CE91F57EECB55BEABDD814A9E497AB7D2B1FFA2D271818B78A696EFCB7FFFB0D6E27B2DE937CE630198A185C293DC63D51FFDDAB7CD79FFB85A2531A6327529D947575E54E925AED2A9EC289967EA722AA3CB0032BBA1B04AB27680E56973AF57F64CE5DFF3A9FDB858CF1FEDF1E49279B754927C0F4437228E0760E28640ACE504FE9C37D5A9E81446AE4ABEEF5D81F32A89A06CDC3AF9AEE33EE298D61A81531A5D6EC652A75BBD1C8AA817E3B352A8943FE6406C6863AC1E9FCB4AE546CCA6364A26D9F7BFBC56A79BB840E951B2CE71BC297E6FAABAA7F3DFE8971ACFC6BB98A7214F2C57F1D6D2EDA1C6B5B7624987928E95F7FDEF4A9D4C416CB5345E9D7CD7711F714C6B1995D8E3E18CCF74F51B4E6086D62C359D51B1AD42E57882B1FDAC247D28E9B9D27E06537DDA27281BAFD2A364927DEA72CE8B9192BBADFDDEF457A24A2FDAD06BBC49FBE7B58D78E84961AD50813FE673E80AF7B914EB0F3B55FDDBE05901B955DCA855E7389E77A3739CE385F67FE36F55EA23208529CAAF543F884AD99E89879D54568A1B359D72D14BB65A1AA71AA3649E42DAE42026625DF24AA567D470207BA272AEF644D2CF25BDA7FD47992F6A63DFE8BA25B1019977B3E6B1B00665539DC61D934EBE6BB98F3CAE65A0662BA62E93B2BEF904652865A110F4B4128CFDD333FD8B0D021E44BF4318C47E162F35FDE0F886B8D78F8D350F702BE969E431AF398EC9D465229EC2706C348ADC16923E505BC9FB77CFE9A3F58166B73165994E6C40B639798DA95B8BA06C4C7AF9AEE7D829F88F1CC7EC228F89139E287CCA3917A8ABC5606CF8D13E1B4079BE3B0464E9C5066473BAA75947405ED5E9264E3C95FD5A4E318D687DD88C1D99C3895E697E9C8058AD0663433BBBC5D145F5FCF6BD69F21D4A23454036B7EDABACEF0FEAF0EEF71AFB80E199BA64F15F229E27FDB35338408CD683B12188DA15B339F65CA6C94A481190CD31A7CFFA1EF1005187273522C5766C4C5D56E289861925432A3582B1FFEEFCBB7EA7DFB1810075C8D22020F3B32E9A5957E9E5BC79CA519CBD577931755989A7EE09CBA311AB743076AC50BAE2EF3BFF7EB744426C62FFDCA6C972491190CD39A78FAAFE6DEB147FAFF2F20CD6CC251F33AB4EBE0FBD2BDF554C44E960EC48D2CD9DE37B93F2BB9DD7F024DD0E6DAEA332A91190C5B37E17F8D12D2BC5BDCACB337539E7EF52328C92A194A5CA6E85F4506F0FE15F77BED66EFEE4FD883E3DB3BF6D380701591A54F56F97F75E752FD1F1AD330194C74AC0BB875657A1AF18AF92C1D846618A72794E3FBC538EBBF9933115FBC9C34C632102B254AC41194541CB4871AF8AC1D465259E04C2142B3A300FA583B1435D7E43F226CC0E379B9895965BB1D2328585E2A68E09C8DEC4B67A6DF2DEAB52E5AA7A66D0F84E25E079DAECABF41463D24B7AAC32C1D8B1AE0EC6A430BAEBB9DE878710EF54C2D0788A8C474096DE5AB6F7EFEB2ABD9C97957CD776CAFD26ADF74AA62E13F03CF5334A86CBF492BE52B960ECA6A16F9E27BFEDC939B1A7657D046479785258904FCCAAEE3E511FAC7BA26EC54367129E0FFE46959EA2752583B1AD4202FFD2D03F6FEEE4A78A0FC848EC8F47409697F5BD5C57E9E53C78770749B9F8CEFA00BB4978ECD9EA65FFD0530E8D621A0E247DA37683B1C1DA71AC8DA43F52FCC6D604027108C8F2B3965D6005661EDE1489D4F719EB3D8F6A0C093C92FD8367781252088A4A57DFF7066383B5E3987F16798E6CA1148F80AC0C6B3D2A92FDD38B59519CB210B567EA9219B4489EA91C46C9D0AB5CF2FE5621672C36181BAC8DC7FE4BC5079D3CC4C421202BC7935FCCFB9A96B7486CEA3C6FA62E2BB825FB07CFC6E3F3B450780AB3EE8F171B8CDDCC702E9B82E7C0164A7108C8CAEA647F7F79E84827A61875CAD178CF800D5397095813FCC98B999FA5C28AC1925394B982B181B7EE8FB5B1D2329E27BD82802C8EF5C18B120869C414A34E3D58E21931ED13F761763C557A8984E7E3406557516E253D57DE606C57EE42B60464F162460DB62297CF8B7D0ECB8BA97D98A33C95F56188B4A6043C5FBCAE464751CC522171BFE414E5566193F0BEC0F99D75A83C53990464F108C8EAF13CB093D6E217536A67A3F4BFCB9EA94BB6DC4AC03A7549B1D8E9EA557673F0DAC1D8596B497F2CE9BF28FE9CA845168F80AC3EEB83D98B3ADD1CBDD8DA8739F2F93C5397D732F46356D860142B499FA8FCA8D856D2E76A23181BA448261F0232A671E21090B5C1339332F6DF880385D1F34F4EFE37F775D42B2E20FB2C53BF98BAACC0BAEA92A5AED3B0549DE9C9A13D549AB21629C53EA90E8D29CB780464EDF03CB88F75B46CA58BEF892F15EE99A9EF5B3149FD43BF723C00768EBE30759980B5FE0809FEE3B554B80194ACB63F86604C22206BC542F18B4A08C8D2FB52F6CF616CB965967BC0570AA36931C1D0426D3F7C78CA6431759980359F8C2ABDE3D24220B691F473B5198C49BEBC0902B2F4524C1D1390E5D1CBFE59BCD2B8168479AEBD570ADF7BEBEFE281D23C045EF79CE89EBE36F6E569C6BECC8AF522204FA67D4371D79A81D85665CB5A781190B58180AC7D9E5487B1D42DF36C2374B6ED0668BDDEFCAD5C2ADC6B52D679CC598CBA73F4E756C6FECC8AF58D479B160A5FFA925B1E5DD41EAAADE4FD8BDC539AF3BD53BAE3134340360EDE07989CA339A9BCAFFAF74D4BCBFD10E829AADD65EED36C586F7C68C34221F03954282751FB26717CD297B18CA4C6E6720C6DECABCC6A23201B17CF68D918A6313D2B4C6BB512A3F2D63D3799BA4CC8F2C67F51A98F083F5E37149668D79E96DC6D4792DECB78DE39A408C8361AC70840CB5622201B1BEF6859EB3FDA6319292B9526610DCA98BA4CC8F2C6BFAAD4C7396A35081B7E081FAADDC4FD8BA458D9379C3F81409C14AB5DF91CEAF0ACC4DC2AA40BB4CA7BB8A1AD000010274944415453F6A3742B99B76AAD4FD615ECDBE4592F8CB14C4F8DCD52A789A0AD0561433B5648DC1FE33590B2282C81401C02B271EBE5FFDC5A1E5DF6069B25DA61C6F33E8F6544941D7E12B3FE50DDAFD3CDC9E91556CF3C50BD02AEFBB6871A47E2FE45A8D2DF8E14A50008C8EAB3D6B71C5ACBF9650B85EF78EDFBEDD96BBDD6BD77DFF7A2ABD4BFC9B2CE1D6F4572B355AFD300ACD551B0B3EDB9C2AAC26586F7A3A45401D9E722208B95A2FC0801591B160A9F85E7336C39BF6CA1F0105AFBFEBB55C8D7AD79CFE91466472EEB23B14006DE55277C18E7EB35BE006C685309C406A902326A90C58BDD4A662B02B2D65C97FFB36C39BF4C0AF78E3B0AF7C4D2F7E18DCA4F575EE4A220F548E39E3D695A27FFC533F7C0ACD77803B0A14D2D101BA40AC85AB9398E59AAD5AE0464ED89A9F5D7727ED9AE95C28E24DE91414B7BA876EFC5EB938602BCF9015BCD27305B299C6B8BAB21ADED5821D868F5CB1F2BD53E9673B9B67359284D316302B2762DE4CF896D39BFEC22EF29A432A40ED08EC4C81376748ABBC8A6F6E3B5D4690076A4FA41548A76ACF0B437F51F3702B236A41AA93CD6F4AFD9B15BC9FFF9B69C5F7695B5A40F253D51DC3D7959B4D768DAF776FEF9AEA47F15F15A87917F5FCB52A146CD35852FD94AD23B353B94D077927EAD3024FE6DDDAE14B15208A2633EBFD70AD7C11CDEAF5C560A53FAEF46BECE37927EACF099A06DB725FDC2F9B71F4BFA9709FB52C342E1376429E98727FFEEBCDF92270A0320DF9EFC3370A9D8E5C0AD97CB18A6200F157EBC536D0CDB527BAE798C889DC5CABE36A41AA9A4FCC8F87C26FFE73D96FC32A0A84EF173E52F557FEA67D817F2B6A63505795910F69EE6FB234640D6861435C8B6A2FCC858CD2DBF0C28A2579A60A14470D6EB74E4EBB1A61D7C0DED8908C2761190B5E103A5B9BE293F326E73CD2F03B24AF14337B4570A01D3A14210B5DCB30FC36857AF30E275A870C33ED234A71D2F6A4F149249D77BBE6F7342A985FA164AF3396C454036153135E9EE56E82F300A0F5426E838D2FC02ADCBDA131184ED8380ACBE542B2CB70AB5F2301D31F9655DF9EE02E3502A309B6B7BAEB032F28E08C2F6B514FB58B6205542FF56F57350915E4C7ED91715FA0B8C06811901582B7AB1B2AF05A9D21B18A99CB698FCB2DB15FA0B8CC61DD50F6AC6D408C0D24BB177220159BC986D7508C8E6C7FBBD65352670855E65F6FE1A5B2300CB2B75223901994FAA2D93B622309E1B6F7E19D398C015568A2F303BE676AC50438900AC8CA5D22592B3B2CF2FE5E74040363F31F9654C63025758280426B503A4DC6D73729E1F2A0460FC9094755DE912C909C8FC5226F4FF87C27D473B7AF9AE19A631813DF59A4EB1D68D4E4B51BC273688AD2D5521D2AD58D9172365BDC2ADA41B65BB8FC678F31199C6040C6E2A4CEBD50EACF66DC76204AC550B495F8980ACB694797CBBEDFD922781E6308D0914D45A7076ACD32D89C8016B5FAF74D3641B119079AD942E7FEC6C63A40CD7E5BB7698C6049CDE53588D5862A5E630EDF850A7538FEBCCE787F4529559D82A2492536AC127D586E2173546A521F957633EAAD159A0A4EF657EFD95A4771402A5A5A41F9EFCFB7E8FBF7D2DE9DB937F3E96F4BB937F7E7EF2FF7B92AA93A866A95066E1DD44AFF72B497FA2707D607F0B85C0F867198FF199A47F92F1F5311E0B857BBA2748BF21E93769BB0300483D2A7358B6FB939173BA72B7DD2A75421805EF34E60B31E20A00C9A44E22DF28DCE061977BBA72B775654E0923E29DC6BC57A3B3003035A94765C81FF3C9B5BAF2A2F6B4CC69616416F2E71EF715FA0B0093916AEFCAA17D2EA6313C4A4D57EE36A62E719198694C008051EADA635B913FE65572BA72B77505CE0DE3F5A57CD7D5DD1A9D0580B14AB955D25661AAA32F7A06D330ACAE2C1D8C6DC5D425AED6C93F8D49FA02005C2147CED29198AEF4E8E5AFA29EA23175897D78D31B588D09009758297D107058F40CA621C7E8D87F72FC4D97F93C311DCFE4BB2EEFD7E82C00B42EE546E25B8502934C4FD8A51E1D1BB6ADFADAF8774C5DC26225FF354A591C0038B154FA157DACAEB4CB313A36941DE91C7FCBD425ACEECA779DBE120F7000907C451F9B89FBA41E1DDB4A7AA0D3C0F896E3EFAFE53B5D4C98771AF3A978900330530B857D2B738CCA607F4BA5FF1CCE0B8CAD53972F339C2BE621661A934DCB01CC4EAFF4F5AE3E2E7A06D3F081D27F0EE705C69DE3753E4A7EB69813EF34E65624FE039891D4394BEC5D69D72B4F55FEDDE9CA5D4C5DA206EF34E656149605307139B6E739123920164B85C029753076551EDF23E3EB317589143AF98BCA6E456E2A8089BAADF4C9FC778A9EC1B82D94BEDCC8D0AECAE35B385E93A94BA472A0B8EB9BC00CC06490CC5F5FCEFD2A0FF73CBEF57599BA444AB1A3C304660046AF17C9FC35F5CAB73D922530FED4F8DA4C5D22B585E2F2CB08CC008C5A8ECAFC7DD13318AF5ED257CA138C6D65DFB2CA1A983375891C3AC5E597119801189D1CD39554E6DFCF52E9DFFBDDE69936BEE638CE0DE331807DC5D42F1B1AA913004621F546E294BAD8CF52795654EE7E0E87CEBE7DE4381690536CE2FFD7E5BB0C0036B137BAB3ED4821D8C0C57207635B8551CA98CFC15AC5FFD3886301FB8ABD5F75C57B0C007BBAAFB481807754662E4A0463C78ACFE1EB1CC765EA12A5C414B1BE55A1BF0070A985D226941F8B7C8DCB2C947E37848B82E214397C9ED108A024EFC30D8B5100342575FED8C72299FF2243E1D75CB5C68676A4B453C6D62AFE6C048D1A3C81D917557A0A00E7E8952E402099FF62A582B163E5293762ED37E50650CB0B11940118A19409FD476274EC3CA582B18DA49B99CEA173F4A7CBD417E032D715AEBFBFD2FED72AD39700AA4B19901D16EEFB58940AC60E953720B65E2B4F33F605B84827DFF78D515D0055A54A30DF88CAFCE73950BE2D9176DB4395293562AD4FC6C8034A5B283C0C78BE478CF003A82655C98B2371333BAB57DE2D9176DFFB92C1B0B53E19A530509AF7BEC6821400D5A40AC8D848FC4D4BE5DD12A956302685C0DBDA4FA0A498FB1A657B0014976A0FCB8DC8BFD855AAD6588D606CB0DEA37FBB8D956C28292620BB57A1BF00662E26D7E26C40C653E5A952B5C66A056383F765EB33F96428252620DB88F40B0085A50AC89E891BD8A057FE24FE63E52B6F61F5A96C7D279F0C25C4A662504F114051A902B207A53BDEA8A5F2E78DB5148C0DBE90ED1C08DE91538AEDE0B8A701286A2502B294724F55B6188C0D2CD5D13795FA887948B11D1CA3FE008A5A294D007158BAE30DEA9577AAB2E5606C60391F92FC91CB6DC57FDF3662A70900055D579A806CEE2B2C53AD56BDECC7A1F5604CB26FAF44923F524BF95D248F0C4031A9B64D9A7B4076A07C539525B6444A692DDBF9BD5FA59798AADB4AF75D9CFB7D0D40411F284DC030E71BD75279ABF13FD47882B1C15A0465286FA5B4DFC539DFD7001496A24AFFDC6B90A57C223FDB8E54667FCA1CD6B29DEBBA46273119398A3113900128226595FEB90664A956A95E148CF5E54E258BB56CE77CAB4A2F3105074ABFA886800C401154E98F9762CAF7BC76AC7124F1EF632DDBB993E80FAB1CC1180F08008A59487AA4F89BD633CD3320EB956F74EC50E3CB1BBBCC5AB6F3FFBA4A2F3146B9BE871BB1CA1240216C9BE49773F3F0238D376FEC326BD9DF8BAE423F311EBDF22DA879A6697E0F01342855FED31C03B25E79A6488E35FDA772EB7B421E0FCE933318DB2AEC3E32B7FB1A804A6E28CDEAC0B96D9B946B746C6CF5C66258A7CA5FD4E9261A952B678C07010055A4287931C7802C5711D823CD6B8AC45394981FC9795B289499C91D8C7DAC793C18016840CAED45E6F42399BAF0E4D0C6B235526A0BD9DFAB17E2C7728E160AAB9A73D5FC1BDA338DBFDC0C80114995D03FA7806CF841C8F123F0B9E61D647856FBDEABD253D4D02B8CC4E70CC48607A3C342E7040092D225F4CFA906D97591C89F532FDFFBC768C674959AA21CDA91E6953600A0012BA519FA9F4B40966BAA722BF255CEFA52F6F79069CCE9E95566546CF7C1E866913303801DD79526209B43C98B85F2FD301C8B119EF3F4F2BD9FF76B7416492D5576546CAB79AD7006D018CF0AB7F3DA91A67F13CB99487C58F03CC6C8335AB69574B746671165A1705FCA595B8C600C40736E2BCDCD6CEA252F72D63B3A12F92AFBE8E57F8FC9CD6BDF1088A55AF56D6D0FC5F7104045A96A90DD29DDF1827225F10F4FE537CB9DCA24788BF1BED23CF21CC766A1509CBA649E18C11880E6A40AC8A65AF2A257DEA993B997B9F05A2804B30466E3B55418A1AF3522463006A02929A62C379A66427AEE60EC58D37CDF4ABA2EFFFB4F6056C74AD22792BE51DD406CC819231803D0845E696E6C53FB61CB1D8C6D4502714A9F29EEB3B85DBECBB3B25418457FA0FC15F6F769C70A69167CFF003463A150BB29E6E636B5921707CAFFF4FE4CD30B626B5B283ED7EF2B316A99CA4AA753922D0461BBC1D8CD8CE70D006EDE24E9A90564C32AAFDC758F369AF62288DA564AF3393D10D35956BDC2C8EF91EA075EE7B58722E006D0B0D85A64532879B152B9E994879A4600DBBA5435F6B60AA33C37CA767F148615922DE4845DD68EC514258091F85AF30CC88651B1523F264762D4A5B4D4E5145E9DBCE6DCA69C973A1D01FB44E15A6E692AF2A2F6508C8A0118914EFE1BDE18A7DF6A14A13C123F0CB52C946F1AEDA5C27574A8F0F94E6114A65718F93A5438B75CEF5DCE762C46C5008CD42DF96E7C635AA1B654E86FE91F98639148DC8A5205485F2AD4F9EBD55EA0B6D069BF6EEBCD51AF927B47E6FAAEFD5CF31BC104AAF97EED0E4CD40F1C7FF389A47F93BA2309AD4EDAFAA4FDB0F0F15F4BFA50D22F0A1F1717FBD9C9FFFE49E6E3FCF0A4FDECCCBFDF48FAF6E49F9FECF95A97FD774B9D7F5D9FFDF70B49D7F63CDED8BC96F42B8560ECDB2BFE5B001885F7657B227DA5F094DDC213E9F0E47FA0D3D55E35F35CD8B0B87D77547F548716F71D7B28E9BDB31F2C80B218296BC33B7A7304E858D2EF14EA3AFDC70BFEE6B711C75BE934C859EBF4C97F75D29756FC526174EC7775BB812BFC42E187FDCF6B77047BFB4ED2AF15460E7F55B527007EEF7BB53B3051072AFF03350472E75917EC470ABF5208C6983E19975E611AFE47B53B82737DAB3022F6447CB700CC48A7FA5312636C0F45798B29B823FF26E6B4B4ED738585317CAF00CCDA97AA7F431E4363C3E2695A2804D9B5AFAF39B58D42107647E31B1D0780AC7AD5BF49B7DC8E4502FF1CF40ADB85D5BEDEA6D88E1502DF9B6A6391100034ED33D5BF71B7D61E8A555E73B45228B3C0B4A6BF3D3F790FDF1323CB0060B610A3045B510D1C6F7A4F4C6D5ED5360A09F91FEA748534808963F5657E0B85D216735B91F69DC292FB8762A517CE376CBCBD3E695DC5BED4F2AD42C1D6273A5D41FDA4627F0054445056C642D20792FEB4764732FB56E10785400C1E43BDBCB54E778F98CA08D16FF566D0B5BB1B01004822282BAD572888DAD5ED4632C313FE1385DA621479456A4B852D8E86C2C6BB5B1CED1641AE6918ED924E47B99E9FFCBBE73BFF3F00B814415979C394CD9F6A7C2BA67683B027E2491F6D38BB17E5553B53ACCFF97797054FE78D6A116C01488EA0ACAEA54EF3697EA47682B4EF1446BD9E2B4CB97CABCB770C0000009108CADAB3FBD4BFDEF9F7BBFFBC947F0AF4B5DE7CEA1F82ADDD000C0000144650361D174DD930CD0200C008FC7F3F25C06F7B4D496F0000000049454E44AE426082
```

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: Well....you can't get the actual file in a query. You would get the byte array in a query. Then you need something in the application where you call this query to convert that byte array into a file.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325338/fastest-way-to-export-blobs-from-table-into-individual-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fastest way to export blobs from table into individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325338/fastest-way-to-export-blobs-from-table-into-individual-files)

Comment: Is there a way to set up SSRS to export and display the individual files? Or can I only extract these in code?