# Convert byte data to image and save? Using SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like below

```
IMAGEID          COVERPAGEIMAGE       IMAGENAME
------------------------------------------------
LME111201908576  0x89504E470D0A1...   NULL
```

I want to convert all the `COVERPAGEIMAGE` is of `varbinary(max)` datatype to a png/jpeg image and update the name in `IMAGENAME` using a SQL query.

The table includes almost 10000 rows of data. I couldn't find a faster way to do it yet any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know exactly with format are the pictures? png or jpeg?

Comment: yes, they are. do you need sample data?

Comment: What do you mean by "*convert to png/jpg*", do you want to *extract* all content from the database and save as local files and file names should be stored in IMAGENAME column?

Comment: I think @Ygalbel was asking if you already know the image format for `COVERPAGEIMAGE` in each and every row of your table. The sample row you've posted has a PNG image, for example, because it starts with the signature bytes `0x89 0x50 0x4e 0x47`.

Comment: @user2316116 exactly

Comment: @AlwaysLearning got it

Answer (score 0):

There is File.WriteAllBytes method that could help to create file from blob data. Example,

```
...
using (var r =  cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (r.Read())
    {
         File.WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\" + (string)r["IMAGEID"]+ ".png",
              (byte[])r["COVERPAGEIMAGE"]);
     }

}
```

Assigning IMAGENAME will depend on how target file names will look like. If filename will be always equal to IMAGEID+".png" like in example above, you might not need that column at all.

Same can be done with only sql: [fastest way to export blobs from table into individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325338/fastest-way-to-export-blobs-from-table-into-individual-files)

Comment: I want to add different name while saving the images and update that name in the table

Comment: in the sample above the file name will correspond to the imageid. you can change this to any other own logic.